# How to return more then 1 value with CASE statement

Tags: t-sql

I need to generate *WHERE IN ()* statement with *CASE*, I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE tbl_column IN ( CASE
                      WHEN @val = 1 THEN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (2), (22)) AS X(a)
                      WHEN @val = 5 THEN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (13), (18), (44)) AS X(a)
                      WHEN @val = 7 THEN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (7)) AS X(a)
                      END
                    )
```

but I got error: ***Subquery returned more than 1 value.***

How I should to make it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `AND` and `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ( @val = 1 AND tbl_column IN (2, 22) 
     OR @val = 5 AND tbl_column IN (13, 18, 44) 
     OR @val = 7 AND tbl_column IN (7)
      ) ;
```

or a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table AS t
     JOIN 
         (VALUES (1,  2), (1, 22),
                 (5, 13), (5, 18), (5, 44)
                 (7,  7)
         ) AS x (val, a)
     ON  @val = x.val
     AND t.tbl_column = x.a ;
```

Answer (score 3):

CASE, by definition, returns only a single value

If you insist on CASE (I find it useful in a UDF, in a slightly different variation), it will look like this

```
select  * 

from    table 

where   case 
            when @val = 1 and tbl_column in (2,22)      then 1
            when @val = 5 and tbl_column in (13,18,44)  then 1
            when @val = 7 and tbl_column in (7)         then 1
        end = 1
```

or

```
select  * 

from    table 

where   case 
            when    (@val = 1 and tbl_column in (2,22)    ) 
                or  (@val = 5 and tbl_column in (13,18,44))
                or  (@val = 7 and tbl_column in (7)       ) 
            then    1
        end = 1
```

Otherwise -

```
select  * 

from    table 

where       (@val = 1 and tbl_column in (2,22)    ) 
        or  (@val = 5 and tbl_column in (13,18,44))
        or  (@val = 7 and tbl_column in (7)       )
```